# Node.js chat on Azure website with SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io, chat, azure-web-app-service

I created a Node.js chat application with Socket.io. It worked well on local environment. When I deployed on my Azure website with an SSL certificate, I got an error. Can you guys help me?

**Server.js:**

```
const connect = require('connect');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./www.reic.vn.key'), 
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./www.reic.vn.crt'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('./bundle.crt'),
  requestCert: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

onst express = require("express");
const http = require('https');//.createServer(options);
const socketio = require('socket.io');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const routes = require('./utils/routes'); 
const config = require('./utils/config'); 

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/chat');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('we are connected!');
});
var chatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    From:String,
    Message:String,
    To:String,
    FromIdWeb: String,
    ToIdWeb: String,
    FromImgWeb: String,
    ToImgWeb:String,
    IsReaded: {type:String,default:'1'},
    CreatedDate:{type:Date,default:Date.now}
});
var Chat = mongoose.model('Message',chatSchema);
//
class Server{
    constructor(){
        //this.port =  process.env.PORT || 3000;
        this.port = process.env.HTTPS_PORT||3000;
        this.host = `127.0.0.1`;
        this.app = express();
        //this.https = https.Server(options.this.app);
        this.http = http.Server(options,this.app);
        //this.http = http.Server(this.app);
        this.socket = socketio(this.http);
    }
    appConfig(){        
        this.app.use(
            bodyParser.json()
        );
        new config(this.app);
    }
    /* Including app Routes starts*/
    includeRoutes(){
        new routes(this.app,this.socket).routesConfig();
    }
    /* Including app Routes ends*/  
    appExecute(){
        debugger;
        this.appConfig();
        this.includeRoutes();
       this.http.listen(this.port, this.host, () => {
            console.log(`Listening on http://${this.host}:${this.port}`);
        });
    }
}
const app = new Server();
app.appExecute();
```

The port 3000 was created in Azure application setting.

I am using Comodo EssentialSSL certificate. I generated Comodo Certificate file into .gem and .key using OPENSSL-Win32.

This is the result when I run the command `node sever.js`:

[image: result]

And this error messsage from client computer:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://www.reic.vn/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=SbXYLozbTo28Waa4k6r1fueDrvVEmjTozpydvGbJQqTXSiNdEiSr03svJNXa2D8gp1UwYUt85axpXvcdIn4Lkr7GBjP%2FUYN4%2BmEyu5nO7%2FtwC4SJHuV%2F8LjYzbCs1oJ97MMFKEYLo7kP4eHATVBBtw%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22hubs%22%7D%5D&tid=10.
```

Hope you guys can help. Thank you!

Comment: maybe you can try to use ssl in your nginx proxy, not your express server.

Answer (score 2):

Since you deployed the app to Azure Web Apps (also known as Azure Web Sites), you'd need to pay attention to the following.

1) You don't have to start the Node.js application running on Azure Web Apps via executing the command `node server.js` manually on Azure. As you have already an entrance file `server.js` and an IIS `web.config` in the root directory of your application, you can directly browse your Node.js application via the URL.

2) You shouldn't create any port variable in Azure application setting,  because of Azure uses a pipe port to translate HTTP requests, and Azure Web Apps only expose **80** & **443** port to public.

Please use the following instead:

```
this.port =  process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

3) Socket.IO uses WebSockets, which are not enabled by default on Azure. To enable web sockets, go into the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com), click the web app from the Web Apps blade, click **All settings** > **Application settings**. Under **Web Sockets**, click **On**. Then click **Save**.

For more details, please refer to [Create a Node.js chat application with Socket.IO in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-chat-app-socketio) and [Secure your app's custom domain with HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate).